# SQL Select Top with Left Join and Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two database tables:

**Cities** with columns:

```
Country_Code | City_Code | City_Name
```

**Countries** with columns

```
Country_Code | Country_Name
```

Based on a few chars entered by User, it checks the `City_Name` column to return results to populate a `City` autocomplete box. The result needs to have the city code, city name, country code, and country name, hence the need for a join.

The query I am using is

```
 SELECT TOP 10 
     ci.Country_Code, ci.City_Code, ci.City_Name, co.Country_Name  
 FROM 
     Cities ci 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     Countries co ON ci.Country_Code = co.Country_Code  
 WHERE 
     ci.City_Name LIKE '@CityName'  
 ORDER BY 
     ci.City_Name
```

The results I get are correct, but the query takes a long time to complete. From what I understand, first, the results contain join of both the tables, then the where clause kicks in to get the specific rows only, which are ordered by City Name and top 10 results returned.

My question is, is there a way to speed up the query. Have the where clause checked, and then only perform the join, better still perform it only on the top 10 results? I tried putting my `WHERE` clause in the `ON` clause, but that gave wrong results.

---

EDIT : @CityName contains 2-3 chars entered by the user and then a '%'.

Comment: Performance troubleshooting is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: What does `@CityName` look like?

Comment: How slow is slow?  There are thousands of cities in the world, not millions.  How big are the tables?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest start with adding **clustered index** on `Countries.Country_Code` (also making it the primary key of the Countries table if it is not already so). An index would sort the table such that the search speed in join is increased.

Comment: There is probably a need to add an index on `CityName` also

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be your query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ci.Country_Code, ci.City_Code, ci.City_Name, co.Country_Name  
FROM Cities ci LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     Countries co
     ON ci.Country_Code = co.Country_Code  
WHERE ci.City_Name LIKE @CityName  
ORDER BY ci.City_Name  ;
```

Quotes should not be needed around `@CityName`.

I don't understand the `LEFT JOIN`.  It suggests that there are cities without a valid `Country_Code` -- and that seems unlikely.

Assuming `@CityName` does *not* start with a wildcard (as suggested by your question), then this can make use of an index.  I would suggest the following indexes:

- `cities(city_name, country_code)`
- `countries(country_code, country_name)`

The second is not needed if `country_code` is a primary key.